# Existence of a differentiable function satisfying a condition

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Show that there exists a real number $\epsilon>0$ differentiable function $f:(-\epsilon, \epsilon)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$e^{x^2+f(x)}=1-\sin(x+f(x)).$$

I have no idea about how to proceed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint : apply the [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem) to the function

$$F(x,y)=e^{x^2+y}-1+\sin(x+y).
$$